# Perl hash slice from hash return from function

Tags: perl

Purely academic question, and I don't see instructions banning them here (*although there is no 'academic'-like tag I could find*).

If I have an existing hash like the following, I can take a slice(?) of it as shown:

```
my %hash = (one=>1, two=>2, three=>3, four=>4);
my ($two, $four) = @hash{'two','four'};
```

Is there a way to do this if the hash is returned from an example function like this?

```
sub get_number_text
{
    my %hash = (one=>1, two=>2, three=>3, four=>4);
    return %hash;
}
```

One way that works is:

```
my ($two, $four) = @{ { get_number_text() } }{'two', 'four'};
```

As I understand it, function returns a list of hash keys/values, the inner {} creates an anonymous hash/ref, and @{} uses the reference to "cast" it to a list aka a hash slice since Perl knows the ref is a hash. (I was a little surprised that the last bit worked, but more power to Perl, etc.)

But is that the clearest way to write that admittedly strange access in one expression?

Comment: it's not because it knows the ref it's a hash; it's a syntactic thing.  `@{ foo }{ bar }` is always a hash slice and always expects foo to be code that generates a hash reference.

Comment: @ysth post an answer here and question will be closed :)

Comment: There's no casting. `@{ EXPR }{ EXRP }` *is* a hash slice. Perhaps you meant dereference?

Comment: Where I wrote "cast", I was not sure what to call the operation, since it is dereferencing the reference to the anonymous hash as well as performing the slice. My updated understanding is that @hash{key} is the syntax for a hash slice, and that @{$ref} is the syntax for dereferencing a (non-trivial) ref. So @{$ref}{key} is the combined syntax for slicing a hash reference; correct? (Thank you @Smlyers for fixing the question.)

Comment: dereferencing happens in specific syntactic forms; it's probably best to not think of @{$ref}{key/keys} as two separate operators.  I strongly suspect this will help you: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, avoid returning a flattened hash (`return %foo`) from a subroutine; it makes it harder to work with without copying it into another hash.  Better to return a hash reference (`return \%foo`).

But yes, that is the clearest way.  Though often lists of hardcoded keys are given using qw:

```
my ($two, $four) = @{ { returnit() } }{ qw/two four/ };
```